# How to install php-devel under CentOS 6.3 x64?

Tags: installation, php5, centos6, dependencies, packages

I'm trying to install php-devel on my CentOS 6.3 VPS and get a failed dependencies test.
From phpinfos():
SYSTEM Linux 2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64 #1 x86_64 NTS

> error: Failed dependencies:
>
> - php(x86-64) = 5.4.6-1.el6.remi is needed by
>     php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64

I've tried the following RPM packages:

- php54w-devel-5.4.6-1.w6.x86_64.rpm
- php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm
- php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm

One of the above package gave me this:

```
root@sv1 [/tmp]# rpm -Uvh php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm
warning: php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 00f97f56: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        php(x86-32) = 5.4.6-1.el6.remi is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libbz2.so.1 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libcom_err.so.2 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libcrypto.so.10 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libedit.so.0 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libgmp.so.3 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libk5crypto.so.3 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libkrb5.so.3 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libncurses.so.5 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libssl.so.10 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libstdc++.so.6 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30) is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.2) is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0) is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.11) is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.5) is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
        libz.so.1 is needed by php-devel-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.i686
```

I don't know how to fix this error and download all the dependencies.
Thank you.

Edit 1 (for quanta):
Here is "**yum repolist**":

```
root@sv1 [/tmp]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.choopa.net
repo id                          repo name                                                              status
base                             CentOS-6 - Base                                                          5,980+366
epel                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                         6,493+1,272
extras                           CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                4
rpmforge                         RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                            2,123+2,310
updates                          CentOS-6 - Updates                                                          499+29
repolist: 15,099
root@sv1 [/tmp]#
```

**rpm -qa | grep php** didn't return any result.
I forgot to mention I'm using cPanel/WHM

Edit 2 after adding the Remi repo:

```
>root@sv1 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Cleaning repos: base epel extras remi remi-test rpmforge updates
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
1 delta-package files removed, by presto

>root@sv1 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                |  12 kB     00:00
 * base: centos.mirror.nac.net
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.choopa.net
 * remi: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
 * remi-test: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.nac.net
base                                                                                         | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                              | 4.5 MB     00:00
epel                                                                                         | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                              | 4.7 MB     00:00
extras                                                                                       | 3.0 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                            | 6.3 kB     00:00
remi                                                                                         | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi/primary_db                                                                              | 330 kB     00:00
remi-test                                                                                    | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-test/primary_db                                                                         |  85 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                                                     | 1.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge/primary_db                                                                          | 2.5 MB     00:00
updates                                                                                      | 3.5 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                           | 2.3 MB     00:00
repo id                      repo name                                                                   status
base                         CentOS-6 - Base                                                               5,980+366
epel                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                              6,493+1,272
extras                       CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                     4
remi                         Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                 96+564
remi-test                    Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                         25+139
rpmforge                     RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                                 2,123+2,310
updates                      CentOS-6 - Updates                                                               499+29
repolist: 15,220

>root@sv1 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# yum install php-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.nac.net
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.choopa.net
 * remi: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
 * remi-test: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.nac.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

>root@sv1 [/etc/yum.repos.d]#
```

Comment: `yum repolist`? `rpm -qa | grep php`?

Comment: Done, see edited post :) second command didn't return any result.

Comment: `yum install php-devel`?

Comment: Thumbs up! :P Package not found, already tried.

Comment: `cat /etc/yum.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to install packages from the `remi` repository (and `remi-test` for PHP 5.4) but the repository isn't enabled or not present on your system.

If you haven't already installed the remi repository, do that now by [installing the appropriate remi-release package](http://rpms.remirepo.net/).

Then you need to edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` and change `enabled=0` to `enabled=1` for the repositories you wish to use. For PHP 5.4 on EL 6, you must enable both `remi` and `remi-test`.

You also need to have the EPEL repository installed in order to use remi, though it seems you already have that one.

Comment: I have downloaded the rpm file on http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/php-devel. Thaks for your answer, but i's not working. Still got the same message "No package php-devel available." :( (Cache is up to date)

Comment: You need to __both__ _install_ and _enable_ the `remi` and `remi-test` repositories. Then run `yum clean all` and then update `yum repolist` in your question.

Comment: Sorry, post updated. :)

Comment: Hm, I see your update. Something is _very_ broken on your system, and I admit I'm not quite sure what it is.

Comment: Well, thanks for the hint, did you see anything wierd in the output? Or it's just because yum do not find the package?

Comment: yum should be finding the package, since it's in the repository. That it doesn't seem to be finding _any_ packages is worrying. How many months has it been since you successfully `yum upgrade`d?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4772/discussion-between-jeremy-dicaire-and-michael-hampton)

Answer (score 4):

Check your `yum.conf` to see if there is an exclude argument, eg.:

```
exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* bind-chroot*
```

This is sometimes set by default when using for example DirectAdmin or other control panel apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a ticket with my VPS provider and cPanel. No update for now.
Answer above accepted because it is the normal way to do it. My server is just crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile cpanel using `/scripts/easyapache` in order to enable extra modules/extensions.